# Swift - C Function is not showing up in Swift

Tags: ios, c, swift, xcode, matlab

I have imported some .c and .h files to Xcode. I am trying to a particular function from those files and transfer to my swift project. The function is

```
void predictX010(const emxArray_char_T *inputString, emxArray_real_T *ypred);
```

However, when I go to my Swift file I type it out and I see this [The photo shows that predictX010() is basically none existent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4iJR.png)

I've put all heard "#import predictX010.h", but it seems that Swift is just not recognizing the function. How do I get that function to work in swift?

*Edit:* Here is emxArray_char_T and emxArray_real_T

```
struct emxArray_char_T {char *data; int *size; int allocatedSize; int numDimensions; boolean_T canFreeData;};



struct emxArray_real_T { double *data; int *size; int allocatedSize; int numDimensions; boolean_T canFreeData;};
```

Comment: How are emxArray_char_T and emxArray_real_T declared? Can you make a *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Hello Martin, I have edited my post. I was wondering what you mean a self contained example? Like create a small example to show how the function should look in swift?

Comment: I was asking for a self-contained example  containing all relevant C declarations because these seem to be from a (non-public?) Matlab SDK (correct me if I am wrong). – I have now put those declarations (as shown by you) into a .h file and cannot reproduce the problem. Did you import the C header files in the bridging header file for Swift?

Comment: If this is in an executable you need import the function in the bridging header. If it is a library you need a modulemap that exposes it to the rest of your framework.

Comment: Hello everyone, I have imported all the C header files in the bridging header file in swift, but nothing really has happened. I’ll try out the modulemap and see if that works